# Publishing message using NServiceBus using Azure Function Cosmos DB Changefeed trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, nservicebus

I have an Azure function and I'm trying to send a message with NServiceBus using Azure ServiceBus transport.

I have successfully got it working following [this doc](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/azure-functions/service-bus) when the endpoint name does not have a “.” or period in the name. E.g.: ASBTriggerQueue

However, my endpoint name has a period, “.” and I do not have control to change the endpoint name.

With period in the name I get the following error:

> The ‘NServiceBusFunctionEndpointTrigger-asb.triggerqueue’ function is in error: ‘NServiceBusFunctionEndpointTrigger-a
> sb.triggerqueue’ is not a valid function name.

Is anyone aware of workarounds to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the trigger function name. Functions doesn't like dots in it. With release 1.2.0 of `NServiceBus.AzureFunctions.InProcess.ServiceBus` you can override trigger function name. See [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/azure-functions/service-bus#basic-usage-azure-function-queue-trigger-for-nservicebus-overriding-the-trigger-function-name) for details

Comment: This was really helpful. Now I feel terrible since I referred to the same documentation. Maybe need some morning tea :)

Comment: Don't feel bad. I've released the minor version just yesterday and you could have not seen it before. Glad to hear it unblocked you.

Comment: Hi Sean, do you happen to know an answer to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415911/using-nservicebus-outbox-with-cosmodb-persistance-in-asp-net-core-application